# Tool for analyzing matlab source codes

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to understand some MATLAB source codes. I don't know exactly which one calls into others and what the relation between the MATLAB functions is. Is there any tool that can help me? I'm basically looking for something like the output diagrams of doxygen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the top of the Current Folder window in the Matlab desktop there is an icon which looks like a small toothed wheel.  Click on that, and from the menu that appears select `Reports`, then `Dependency Report`.  There is a variety of other reports that you may find useful too.  You may also want to investigate the Matlab Profiler.