# MATLAB code analysis and visualization tools?

Tags: matlab, static-analysis, code-visualization

I just picked up a MATLAB codebase that's light on documentation and original developers (who all shot through long ago).

I'm comfortable with MATLAB but could still use some static analysis tools to visualize the program for a quick idea how it works, without acquainting myself with all 148 source files...

I can't find anything like this for MATLAB -- searches return plenty on m-lint results but that's not what I'm looking for, I'm particularly interested in code structure visualization.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can use doxygen plus an appropriate filter, such as [UsingDoxygenwithMatlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab/content/Doc/html/index.html).

Be sure to set `EXTRACT_ALL = YES` to get auto-generated documentation for code without comments.  There are other parameters for generating call trees and such, not sure if they work with the converted MatLab code.

Answer (score 3):

Some of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798431/tool-for-analyzing-matlab-source-codes/9798939) may be useful.  And don't forget the `publish` function.