# Matlab function for dependency analysis

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I'm looking for a programmatic way to run a dependency analysis. The analysis would tell me all the toolboxes used by a given project.

The function would be similar to "[Tool for analyzing matlab source codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798431/tool-for-analyzing-matlab-source-codes)" and  the App deployment process checks [documented here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/dependency-analysis.html).

The key difference is that I want to do this using a script and *not a GUI*. The ultimate objective is to run this as a pre-commit hook to prevent the introduction of new toolbox dependencies into the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

depfun: List dependencies of function or P-file

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/depfun.html

and

fdep: a pedestrian function dependencies finder

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17291-fdep-a-pedestrian-function-dependencies-finder

You can use the latter as an example, for inspiration and build your own wrapper around depfun, or as an example of use.